# Make a diagonal using zero for integer print in Java

Tags: java

i have a problem with my code. I'm making a program that should display like this:

```
0 2 3 4 
5 0 7 8
9 10 0 11
12 13 14 0
```

Here's my code:

```
int rows = 4, count1=1, count2=4;

    for(int i=1; i<=rows; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=rows; j++){
            if(j==count1){
                System.out.printf("0");
            }else{
                System.out.print(count1);
            }
        }
        if(i<=rows){
            count1++;
            count2--;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
```

But the output shown is like this:

```
0 1 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 3 0 3
4 4 4 0
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you

Comment: `count1` what you print should be incremented within the inner loop.

Comment: Why isn't `11` skipped while `6` is skipped?

Comment: To fix your problem, think about when you need to increment `count1`. Explain **in words** when this should happen. Also, why do you have `count2`?  It doesn't appear to be used for anything.

Comment: Set some breakpoints and start your debugger. That way, you will learn a lot more than by asking on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter (e.g. `count` in the code given below) initialized with `1` to print the values. Print `0` when `i==j`. Increase the counter whether you print the value of the counter or `0`.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 4, count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++, count++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    System.out.printf("%3d", 0);
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%3d", count);
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
  0  2  3  4
  5  0  7  8
  9 10  0 12
 13 14 15  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a need for two counters. Increment `count1` on EVERY iteration of your inner loop. Replace the first condition with `if (j == i)`.